# Index Match Function, match_type is 1 and lookup_array is unsorted data

Tags: excel

I am given each users registration date for a site as well as a date for each of the product pages they visited on my site.

I am trying to see the last product page a user visited before they registered for the site. So I want to match the closest date to the registration date for each user.

I used the Index Match Function but the dates in the lookup array are not sorted in ascending order for when each user visited a product page.

Here is my current code:

`=INDEX(C1:J1,MATCH(MIN(ABS(C2:J2-A2)),ABS(C2:J2-A2),1))`

When `match_type = 1,` I get a `NA`.

Anyone have any workarounds or other ideas how to do this?

Expected Result: Find last product page viewed based on date and time that is closest to the registration date.

[image: Here is a picture of the excel sheet]

Comment: Can you add some sample data, as well as the expected result, to your question?

Comment: So it doesn't matter if the product date is before or after the registration date, as long as it's the nearest? Or is it the last one before the registration date (which is in column A)? Using abs with match type 0 would give you the nearest either before or after A2, which I don't think you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the nearest date, use your formula or something like it with match type 0

```
=INDEX(C$1:J$1,MATCH(TRUE,ABS(C2:J2-A2)=MIN(ABS(C2:J2-A2)),0))
```

If you want the nearest date but only if it is before the reg date, use

```
=INDEX(C$1:J$1,MATCH(1,(C2:J2=MAX(IF(C2:J2<A2,C2:J2)))*(C2:J2<>""),0))
```

Must be entered as array formulas using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Note that the second formula gives #N/A for row 2 because there are no dates before the reg date.

Comment: When I try the second formula, I get an error. But yes the idea is right, I need to find the nearest date before the registration date.